# Keep Bottom of TableView Visible When Keyboard Shows With Autolayout in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, tableview

I have a tableview with a textview for entering text immediately below it similar to Apple Messages. When the user begins to enter text and the keyboard appears, I want the following behavior similar to IOS Messages.

1. If the keyboard will not cover anything,  the visible part of the tableview remains unchanged.
2. If the keyboard will cover something, the tableview moves up just enough so that its bottom-most filled cell is just above the keyboard.

Because I'm using autolayout, I currently have a constraint between the tableview and the textview below it.  Also, the project has IQKeyboard which manages a lot of other views involving textfields and textviews.

The constraint combined with IQKeyboard accomplishes 2.  When the keyboard appears, the keyboard pushes the textview up.  The textview pushes the tableview up. So if the tableview is fully populated, you see the last cell of the tableview above the textview above the keyboard as desired.

However, 2. is not working.

if the tableview is not filled, the keyboard pushes up the textview which pushes up the tableview so that you longer see the top of the tableview.

I have tried adjusting the contentOffset property of the tableview when the Keyboard Shows and this sort of works but the tableview initially moves up before coming back down.  I think this is because the notification to change the offset property does not fire until after the keyboard has begun to move up.

I also tried adjusting the tableview height to its content but this causes the textview to expand to fill the difference due to constraints.

```
Content offset approach - problem is that content offset adjusts too late
//register for keyboard notifications and in handler:
if let infoKey  = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey],
   let rawFrame = (infoKey as AnyObject).cgRectValue {
     let keyboardFrame = view.convert(rawFrame, from: nil)
     self.heightKeyboard = keyboardFrame.size.height
     UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
             self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.heightKeyboard!, 0, 0, 0);
     })
}
```

Can anyone suggest a way to mimic the behavior of Apple Messages?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Instead of *"pushing up the tableview"* have your constraints *shrink* the size of the tableview, and scroll the tableview to the bottom.

Comment: When I shrink the tableview, it shrinks but the textview below it expands to fill the difference.  This is because the tableview bottom is constrained to the textview top.

Comment: The same thing happens when instead of shrinking the table, I change the constraint between the table and the textview.  The textview expands rather than the table moving down. I think this is due to the tableview being constrained at the top and the textview being constrained at the bottom. The keyboard is pushing the whole superview up and down due to IQKeyboardManager which is generally a great drop in.  I think I need to modify the tableview inset but do so in a different place so it happens before or simultaneously with the keyboard appearing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

- constrain the top of the tableView to the top of the view
- constrain the bottom of the tableView to the top of the textField
- constrain the bottom of the textField to the bottom of the view
- create an `@IBOutlet` for the textField's bottom constraint

When the keyboard is shown, change the `.constant` of the textField's bottom constraint to the height of the keyboard view.

This will move the textField up, and because it's top is constrained to the bottom of the tableView, it will also move the tableView's bottom edge up.

Then scroll to the bottom of the tableView.

Layout:

[image]

Initial hierarchy, with 20 rows (scrolled to the bottom):

[image]

Hierarchy view (tableView background color set to green, so we can see its frame):

[image]

View after the keyboard is shown:

[image]

Hierarchy after the keyboard is shown:

[image]

Little tough to see from static screen caps, but the frame of the green rectangle (the tableView background) is now shorter... the user can still scroll up and down to see all the rows, but the bottom of the tableView is still constrained to the top of the textField.

When you the keyboard is dismissed, set the `.constant` of the textField's bottom constraint back to Zero.

You can see a full, working example project up on GitHub: https://github.com/DonMag/KBAdjust

Comment: Thanks for this iin depth answer.  It totally works for cases where the tableview is fully populated.  However when the tableview only has one or two filled cells in it, I would like those cells to remain visible when the keyoard appears so I'd like the tableview not to move.  I tried adjusting the tableview to textview constraint downward by keybaord height (to about -300) but this blows the textview up to fill the void.  Perhaps I should simulaneously increase top ofTableview to top ofView constraint to push tableview down at same time.  Will try this and let you know if it works.

Comment: You must not have your constraints quite right. I put a full, working example project up on GitHub: https://github.com/DonMag/KBAdjust ... see the comments at the beginning of `viewDidLoad()` to change from only a few rows to lots of rows.

Comment: Thanks so much for so much help.  I could not open your project--probably because I'm running Xcode 8.3 but I copied over your code.  It does work although for me the upper table rows disappear and then come back down from top.  This is different than imessage where the tableview stays totally still as the keyboard and textview jump up.  However, it probably has something to do with the rest of my code so am marking your answer correct.